# Estimates on logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, logarithms

Let $0<2b<a$, then 
$$
\left[\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right]^p\leq c\left[\frac{a-b}{b}\right]^{p-1},
$$
for some positive constant $c$.
I have checked using the fact that $\log(1+\zeta)\leq \zeta$ for all $\zeta\geq 0$ for $\zeta=\frac{a-b}{b}$, we get
$$
\left[\log\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\right]^p\leq c\left[\frac{a-b}{b}\right]^{p}.
$$
But we want the power to be $p-1$ on the R.H.S.
Can someone kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Proof for  $p \geq 2$. [See last line of the answer for the case $1<p<2$]

Let us show that the inequality holds with $c=2^{2p-1}$. What we have to show is $(log x )^{p} \leq 2^{p} (x-1)^{p-1}$ where $x =\frac  a b$. Note that $x >2$. This is equivalent to showing that $y^{p} \leq 2^{p} (e^{y}-1)^{p-1}$ where $y=\log x >\log 2$. Let us prove this last inequality by considering the cases $\log 2 <y <2$ and $y \geq 2$. In the first case we have $2^{p} (e^{y}-1)^{p-1} >2^{p}>y^{p}$ because $e^{y} >2$. Since $2^{2p-1} >2^{p}$ we are done.

In the second case $2^{2p-1} (e^{y}-1)^{p-1} >2^{p} (y^{2p-2})>y^{p}$ since $e^{y} >1+\frac {y^{2}} 2$ and  $2^{p} y^{p-2}>2^{p} 2^{p-2}=2^{2p-2} >1$. This finishes the proof.

EDIT: Using the inequality $e^{y} >1+\frac {y^{n}} {n!}$ with $n >\frac p {p-1}$ the above proof can be modified to get the inequality with  larger constant $c$.

Comment: So in the last argument $y^{p-2}\geq 2^{p-2}$ you are using $p\geq 2$?

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, my proof seems to work only for $p \geq 2$. But you stated no assumption on $p$.  The inequality is obviously false for $p=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your proof. But the above fact also true for $1<p<2$, but unable to proceed.

Comment: @Mathlover My method works for $1<p\leq 2$ also if we increase the value of the constant. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.